# Screenresolution on iPad and iPad Retina

Tags: ios, ipad, screen-resolution

I have made a Windows program, which I want to translate to an iPad app. The graphics in my Windows program is made to a screen with a resolution of 1024 x 768 px, which is perfect for the old iPads.

What happens if I use the same Graphics on a iPad Retina ? Will the graphics only be shown in part of the screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't used vector graphics then you're images will look blurry on retina devices. So you need to make new graphics 2 times the size of your originals to make it look crisp.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/high-resolution/ for more information regarding graphics for retina graphics.